# Change the role of a distant user without having to relog

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to change the role of a user, using the FOSUserBundle. The problem is: if the user is logged at the same time, he has to relog to see the new role.

Any solutions ?

Comment: How you got your answer? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Security Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html), there's a `always_authenticate_before_granting` option. There's not much informations about that, but I've tried it with custom roles loading from database and it does the trick. It looks like everytime you will make a new request, the security component will reload roles.

So if you want to make sure your roles are refreshed and reloaded in your user session just set this option to `true`in your `security.yml` :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting:  false
```

Comment: That seems to double the processing of the page in the latest symfony versions... :(

Comment: Will it increase Database IO?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->refreshUser($user);
```

See FOS/UserBundle/Model/UserManager.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not really what i'm looking for.
I can already refresh the roles of a user in the current session.
What I'm trying to do is refresh the role of a distant user.

Let's say I'm an admin, and I want to change the role of a connected user. He would have to relog to see the new role... How can I avoid that and make it instantanely change?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

1: You must enable switch_role: true in your firewall configuration.
2: Next you must allow the role of ROLE_ADMIN to be able to switched into another role.
3: just make link to the ?_switch_role=userNameCanonical

its mostly done by symfony security fos has nothing to do with the role switching.