# How to assign an extra role to an admin

Tags: symfony

On my website, I have admins who have a bunch of roles.
I want to limit access to a section to SOME admins, so I ask for a specific role to be granted before entering. The admins need to have the "ROLE_REPORT" role assigned to them to access the /report page.

Here's my code:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_REPORT : ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MERCHANT:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL: ROLE_MERCHANT
        ROLE_ONLINE_CHECKOUT: ROLE_MERCHANT
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_MERCHANT, ROLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL, ROLE_ONLINE_CHECKOUT]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:

        # Section Report
        - { path: /report(.*), roles: ROLE_REPORT}
```

For some reason, my admin, when the role is granted, cannot access the page. I'm thinking it has to do with the role hierarchy.

Let me know if I can provide you with more info.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try to logout/login again? Roles are not automatically refreshed...

Comment: @jperovic : It works. I feel lame for posting this. Post your comment as answer so I can accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you need to logout/login again in order for new roles to take effect.

However, there is another option. According to Security reference there is an option `always_authenticate_before_granting` which, if set to `true`, will refresh token on each request. Symfony will go to DB each time to refresh roles.

[iamdto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386608/662615) provided the similar answer with example and links

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new role, for example ROLE_ADMIN_REPORT and modify your security in this way:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_REPORT : ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MERCHANT:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL: ROLE_MERCHANT
        ROLE_ONLINE_CHECKOUT: ROLE_MERCHANT
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_MERCHANT, ROLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL, ROLE_ONLINE_CHECKOUT]
        ROLE_ADMIN_REPORT: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_REPORT]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_control:

    # Section Report
    - { path: /report(.*), roles: ROLE_REPORT}
```