# Invalidate session for a specific user in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have written a system in which a background PHP process (written using the [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle)) processes messages from a message queue. The worker process updates user accounts. This may include a change in the user roles.

The problem is that a user won't notice any changes in his roles while being logged in. The new roles only get applied after logging out and in again. From a security perspective this is not desirable. A user should loose any role as soon as an administrator takes away privileges from that user in the backend system.

The question is: **How can a session for a specific user be updated with the new roles?** Or when that is not possible, how can the session be invalidated?

Note that in the background process we don't have an active `security.context` or `request` that we can use. Code like this therefore doesn't work:

```
$this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this in several ways:

1) via `security.always_authenticate_before_granting`

You can force `Symfony` to refresh user on each request, effectively reloading all roles with it.

See this SO question/answer: 
[Change the role of a distant user without having to relog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220975/change-the-role-of-a-distant-user-without-having-to-relog)

2) Via `EquatableInterface`:

You need to implement `isEqualsTo(User)` which in turn should compare everything with `User` class, including roles.

See this link: [Create a User Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-class)

3) Finally, you can use `DBMS` to store sessions. Then, it's just matter of find the record and delete it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at the performance impact of the first option. Any idea whether option 3 can be done with Memcache or Redis as a session store as well?

Comment: I didn't use any of those so far, but knowing the capability of each I would say that it's totally doable ;) As for the #1, I did use this option on project with ~100 users and I didn't notice any impact. This makes sense since 100 users is pretty low...