# Where does Symfony store the information on the loged in users?

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-4.3

I have started a project with symfony 4.3.
The code for registering and authenticating users was generated using the console, with `bin/console make:auth` and `bin/console make:registration-form`, and I didn't really modify it beyond that.

Now, I have some page which are restricted to certain user roles. This is configured in config/packages/security.yaml, wih for exemple

```
security:
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I also have a form that allows me to modify a user's role. Now this is the crux of the issue : **if I modify the role of a user which is currently connected, the pages that he can access do not change until he logs out and logs in again**. Since the database is properly updated, this means the his former role is still stored somewhere. I need to know where, so that I can update it without forcing him to log out and in again.

I don't think that it is in a plain file, as `find . -mmin 5` find nothing after I create a new user and log in as them. I've seen var/cache//session mentioned, but I don't have this directory. I see nothing in the database either, nor any cookies with the information on my browser.

So, where does Symfony store information on logged in users ?

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676864/11410707

This one solves (part of) my issue, but only if I modify the current user, not if I modify another. I'm also still interested in where tokens are stored.

---

The question has been locked even though the two links don't provide the answer, so here it is for the record :

The info on logged in users is stored in the PHP sessions of each user. In turn, the PHP sessions are stored as plain file in the directory /var/opt/remi/php73/lib/php/session/ (at least on my CentOS install).

Each session can only be accessed by the corresponding user, identified by the cookie PHPSESSID. Thus, it's not possible to refresh a remote user's session directly.

Comment: User are stocked in sessions: You could find how to refresh it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session)

Comment: Everywhere that I looked, only the current user user's session was accessed, is it possible at all to access the session of another user ?

Comment: You can't access session of other user. I think you should update the `refreshUser` method of the `UserProvider` to refresh roles when user come and session is reloaded.

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220975/change-the-role-of-a-distant-user-without-having-to-relog

Comment: @yivi The first question explains how to refresh the current user, while I want to refresh another arbitrary user. I don't think that I can adapt the method explained it I can't access that other user's session. The second question is what I want to do, but the method described didn't seem to work for me. Since there wasn't much explanation I couldn't troubleshoot, hence my current question.

Comment: @GrenierJ I'm going to look into that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new token and refresh

```
$user->addRole('ROLE_****');

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user,null,'main',$user->getRoles());

$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userManager->refreshUser($user);
```